# Windows freezes/turns off

Tags: windows-7, laptop, freeze

I have a dell laptop, with Windows 7 ultimate installed. Now, when it boots, it's on for several seconds, then the laptop freezes, and all I can see on the screen are random color, like if it was a problem with graphics. I went on and booted it in safe mode, to make sure it won't happen again, and nothing happened. Then I cleaned it a bit(software), then tried to boot into win7 regular again. Freeze again, same screen. Then I tried to reinstall the system, but when Windows starts copying files, it just turns off.

I checked the temperature, and it's not overheating. Any ideas? HDD bad clusters first came to mind, but can't find a way to test it.

Comment: Try booting it from some linux distro on USB/CD/DVD and running a disk/memory scan, if possible.

Comment: Just tried, but whenever it loads the system, it just freezes, and shows a screen like as if it's a graphics problem. Could it be?

Comment: Absolutely.  I don't think that will help, but did you tried maybe connecting external display/TV?

Comment: I think it could be a RAM problem, and once the operating system starts to load things it freezes. If you have the possibility of trying another RAM on the computer, or if it has 2, removing one and the other, you could check if it is

Comment: @Hex, no, I don't see how that's going to help. But it loads first, then waits for around 10 seconds, then turns of. Given the behavior, I'd say CPU overheat, but it isn't. What's interesting is that it shows freezing screen when OS loads(windows from hdd, ubuntu from live cd), but shuts down when I try to install new system.